# Indian English . Meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning

The man card goes quack. What is the meaning of this with reference to Hillary Clinton and Donald Trump ?

Comment: where did you hear this?

Comment: I suggest you remove Indian English from the title. The question (and answer) are not specific to Indian English. Consider making the title specific to the sentence you are asking about, however.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not indicate what "Indian English" has to do with a phrase purportedly related to two Americans running for President.

Answer (score 1):

It is  Hilary's answer to the "woman card" that Trump mentioned recently:

> - Yesterday Hillary gave a whupping to Donald with that ***[woman card](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-editorials/the-man-card-goes-quack-hillary-clinton-makes-history-and-also-exposes-donald-trump-as-a-globalist/)***  saying a man you can bait with a tweet is not a man to trust with nuclear weapons.

***[quack](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quack)*** refers to the supposed solutions that Trumps appears to have to solve problems:

​

> - (disapproving) a person who dishonestly pretends to have medical skills or knowledge.

​
(Cambridge dictionary)

Comment: Or perhaps an allusion to Donald *Duck*?